# Find matrix $\mathbf{V}$ that gives constant value of $\mathrm{tr}(\mathbf{U}^T\mathbf{V}\mathbf{U})$ for degenerate eigenvectors $\mathbf{U}$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a symmetric matrix $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ which has degenerate eigenvalues.
Let's say the degenerate eigenvectors of matrix $\mathbf{A}$ as $\mathbf{U}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ (with $m < n$ as the number of degenerate eigenvectors for **the same** eigenvalue).
Please note that the degenerate eigenvectors matrix $\mathbf{U}$ can have multiple possible values while still being the valid eigenvectors of $\mathbf{A}$ because of its degeneracy.

How can I find a matrix/linear operator $\mathbf{V}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ which gives the constant value of $\mathcal{L}=\mathrm{tr}(\mathbf{U}^T\mathbf{VU})$ for all possible values of $\mathbf{U}$?
Or what property does $\mathbf{V}$ has to have?

Comment: Are the selected eigenvectors (the columns of $\mathbf U$) necessarily orthonormal? If not, then I don't believe that any such non-zero $\mathbf V$ exists

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. I would still be interested in hearing what exactly you had in mind and if I correctly guessed what you were trying to say

Comment: Yes, it is exactly what I'm looking for! I've also tried it numerically and you are right. I just don't get why we can apply the right-multiplication with $\mathbf{W}$ that still makes it valid eigenvectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, your question can be equivalently expressed as follows.

> Let $S$ denote an $m$-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ (which happens to correspond to a single eigenspace of a symmetric matrix $\mathbf A$). Characterize the matrices $\mathbf V \in \Bbb R^{n \times n}$ such that for every $\mathbf U$ whose columns form an orthonormal basis of $S$, the function $\mathcal L(\mathbf U) = \operatorname{tr}(\mathbf U^T \mathbf V\mathbf U)$ is constant.

In fact, this will be true for **every** matrix $\mathbf V$.

Let $\mathbf U_0$ denote a matrix with orthonormal columns whose columns span $S$. $\mathbf U$ will be another such matrix if and only if there exists an orthogonal matrix $\mathbf W$ such that $\mathbf U = \mathbf U_0 \mathbf W$. With that, we find that
$$
\operatorname{tr}(\mathbf U^T \mathbf V\mathbf U) = \\
\operatorname{tr}((\mathbf U_0 \mathbf W)^T \mathbf V(\mathbf U \mathbf W)) = \\
\operatorname{tr}(\mathbf W^T \mathbf U_0^T \mathbf V\mathbf U_0 \mathbf W) = \\
\operatorname{tr}(\mathbf W \mathbf W^T \mathbf U_0^T \mathbf V\mathbf U_0) =\\
\operatorname{tr}(\mathbf U_0^T \mathbf V\mathbf U_0)
$$

Comment: Thanks for this! Is there any reference that explains why $\mathbf{U}\rightarrow\mathbf{UW}$ is still a valid degenerate eigenvectors for an orthogonal matrix $\mathbf{W}$?

Comment: @Firman No reference, but here's a justification: each column of $\mathbf U \mathbf W$ is a linear combination of columns of $\mathbf U$, and the linear combination of "degenerate eigenvectors" from the same eigenspace is another such eigenvector. The other key point is that the orthogonality of $\mathbf W$ ensures that the columns of $\mathbf U \mathbf W$ will be orthonormal.